# Response message logging issue in SoapHeaderAuthentication with Camel CXF

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf, blueprint-osgi, cxfrs

I am using camel cxf for my webservices and want to validate the credentials of hits from soap UI. For which i am using cxf interceptors, post which credential is getting validated, but i am not able to print the error message in json/xml format in Soap UI response.

Below is my blueprint:-

```
<cxf:rsServer id="testingService"
    address="http://127.0.0.1:8183/test/myWebserviceEndPoint"
    serviceClass="com.test.SerFac">
    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </cxf:providers>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
          <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
          <bean class="com.test.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor" />
   </cxf:inInterceptors>
   <cxf:outInterceptors>
          <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
   </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:rsServer>
```

Below is the BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor.java

```
public class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor extends SoapHeaderInterceptor {

protected Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

/** Map of allowed users to this system with their corresponding passwords. */
private Map<String,String> users;

@Required
public void setUsers(Map<String, String> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Override public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    // This is set by CXF
    AuthorizationPolicy policy = message.get(AuthorizationPolicy.class);

    // If the policy is not set, the user did not specify credentials
    // A 401 is sent to the client to indicate that authentication is required
    if (policy == null) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("User attempted to log in with no credentials");
        }
        sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
    }

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Logging in use: " + policy.getUserName());
    }

    // Verify the password
    String realPassword = users.get(policy.getUserName());
    if (realPassword == null || !realPassword.equals(policy.getPassword())) {
        log.error("Invalid username or password for user: " + policy.getUserName());

        sendErrorResponse(message, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}

private void sendErrorResponse(Message message, int responseCode) {
    Message outMessage = getOutMessage(message);
    outMessage.put(Message.RESPONSE_CODE, responseCode);

    // Set the response headers
    Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders =
        (Map<String, List<String>>)message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
    if (responseHeaders != null) {
        responseHeaders.put("WWW-Authenticate", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Basic realm=realm"}));
        responseHeaders.put("Content-Length", Arrays.asList(new String[]{"0"}));
    }
    message.getInterceptorChain().abort();
    try {
        getConduit(message).prepare(outMessage);
        close(outMessage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private Message getOutMessage(Message inMessage) {
    Exchange exchange = inMessage.getExchange();
    Message outMessage = exchange.getOutMessage();
    if (outMessage == null) {
        Endpoint endpoint = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);
        outMessage = endpoint.getBinding().createMessage();
        exchange.setOutMessage(outMessage);
    }
    outMessage.putAll(inMessage);
    return outMessage;
}

private Conduit getConduit(Message inMessage) throws IOException {
    Exchange exchange = inMessage.getExchange();
    EndpointReferenceType target = exchange.get(EndpointReferenceType.class);
    Conduit conduit =
        exchange.getDestination().getBackChannel(inMessage, null, target);
    exchange.setConduit(conduit);
    return conduit;
}

private void close(Message outMessage) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = outMessage.getContent(OutputStream.class);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

}

Response from soap UI:-

In xml format:-

```
<xml/>
```

In raw:-

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Basic fLaWs3dvcmQ6cGFzc3dvcmQx
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8183
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=realm
Server: Jetty(8.1.17.v20150415)
```

Can anyone help how to print the error messages in soap UI if i give wrong credentials?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but where are you throwing a `Fault` in case of an authentication error? Also, why do you extend `SoapHeaderInterceptor` if you are not using its implementation anywhere in your sub-class? Or do you?

Comment: Thanks Ralf, Tried with AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> with Fault instead of SoapHeaderAuthentication and got the xml response as given.  But i am  not able to convert that in to JSON format.  Is it possible to print a Fault error message in Json format?

Comment: Fault fault = new Fault("Invalid username or password for user: " + policy.getUserName(), java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal());
            fault.setStatusCode(403);
            throw fault;

Comment: SOAP implies XML. Which part of the fault message would you like to be JSON encoded? (And why?)  Can you update your question with the response you'd like to receive?

Comment: @Ralf, I am using Restful service,

This is what I am looking for 

Response in XML tab:-
<Response xmlns="http://..../myservice">  
   <errorMessage>Invalid username or password for user: Test</errorMessage>
</Response>


Response in JSON tab:-
{
   "errorMessage": "Invalid username or password for user: Test"
}

Comment: The server will send you one response. Either XML or JSON encoded. How you set up CXF to respond with JSON encoded messages I don't know.

Comment: Maybe it automagically does the right thing based on the `Accept` header you send in your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing the ContainerRequestFilter resolved this issue.  For more suggestion, please post it.

https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1003506

http://javatech-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/jax-rs-filters-example.html